# ArcPy: Aggregate points using multiple aggregation distances and output names

Tags: arcpy, parameters, aggregate-points

I would like to be able to run a whole load of aggregate polygons with a variety of aggregation distances, using Arcpy. I have successfully done it using model builder, but specifically want to do it using ArcPy as I am comparing the environments for research as a part of degree. 
The code I have below is a start, but it errors out and was hoping someone would be able to help!

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:/temp/Data.gdb"

in_point_features = "E:/points.shp"
out_feature_class = "E:/points"+aggregation_distance ".shp"
aggregation_distance = ["100 meters", "200 Meters"]

arcpy.AggregatePoints_cartography(in_point_features, out_feature_class, aggregation_distance)
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to GSE. I guess you're getting an error due to your `out_feature_class` as it's defined incorrectly. Also, if you want to run this process for multiple aggregation distances, you need to create a loop.

Try this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"E:\temp\Data.gdb"

in_point_features = r"E:\points.shp"
aggregation_distance = ["100 meters", "200 Meters"]

for distance in aggregation_distance:
    out_feature_class = """E:\points_{0}_meters.shp""".format(distance[0:2])
    arcpy.AggregatePoints_cartography(in_point_features, out_feature_class, distance)
```

Note the three following things:

- The outfile is created within the loop, so it is set differently for each loop. Note that spaces in file names are problematic. Therefore I used the `[0:2]` expression and added the `_meters` separately.
- Try to use `r"C:\Pathname"` instead of `"C:\Pathname"`. This helps to prevent errors with paths. Also, `\` usually works better than `/` in paths.
- By using the built-in function `.format()`, putting together strings becomes much easier. Simply insert variables in `{}` and refer to them in the format function.

In case this wasn't what you're after, please update your question with some extra information.

---

**Update 4th of March '16**:

I was thinking about the variable for the output shape name again. The method in my code isn't the prettiest of options as you'd have problems with distances that only have 2 digits or more than 3. The easiest option would be to create another list with the *plain numbers* of your `aggregation_distance` parameter. Or you could use a `.find()` approach and locate the space in the `aggregation_distance` strings and isolate everything to the left of the space.